# PWM Controlled 12V Fan with dc-dc converter

Tags: rpi.gpio

I got my RPI3 cooled by a 5v dc fan and it only activates when it reaches 55°C so everything is fine i control it with PWM.

Now i want to cool it with a bigger 12V DC fan the problem is i need 12V, either from external source or from the PI itself and in this case i need a dc-dc converter which i found [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MT3608-2A-Max-DC-DC-Step-Up-Power-Module-Booster-Power-Module-For-Arduino-3-5V/32675974827.html?spm=a2g0s.13010208.99999999.263.9hvsBQ)

the thing is i can't find on the internet a similar project and how to cable it that's why i'm asking for help.

tried to do it myself on fritzing but i really dont think its good.

update : assuming the fan is a 4 wires (12v/grd/pwm/rpm) i did this on fritzing:

[image]

yellow wire is connected to PWM gpio.

Comment: Are you not concerned about overloading the Pi?

Comment: @MohammadAli how come ? The fan runs at 12v 0.20A

Comment: that's like 2.4 watts you sure your power supply is capable of that plus the spike in power required normally around 4-6 watts to start the fan?

Comment: @MohammadAli What should i do to know how much my Pi consumes ? Is the limit the same for all PIs ? Or does it depend of my power supply ?

Comment: It's more about the power supply as the pis 5v line is just a pass through of the USB power

Comment: It might be better to have a 12v power supply and then convert it down to 5v, eg with a car usb charger of suitable quality. (Check the 0v is common).

Comment: I got a normal power supply 5V 2.5A, so 12.5W, quite enough no ?

Comment: @meuh why go from 12v to 5v when the fan needs 12v to work properly ?

Comment: @MohammadAli i did not undestand the usb splitter part, do you mean i should use a power bank to power the fan ? I'm looking for a solution where everything is done via the PI so i could have total control of the fan, could you explain your idea again please.

Comment: @MohammadAli i understand. Still if i power the fan through the usb hub it will only get 5V which it's all about. Do dc-dc converters with usb input exists ? If they do i could use one to go 5v to 12v from the pi's usb then power the fan and control it with the pwm gpio. If that doesn't work i will for an external power to power it like a power bank or batteries.

Comment: @MohammadAli yes ! But shouldn't it be a male usb so i can put it in the pi ? Or do i need a male-male usb converter between them?

Comment: @MohammadAli that's right, my bad , so pi's usb gives 5v to that dc dc converter which output gives 12v to the fan and i control it with its pwm output directly via the pwm gpio. I will try that and keep this thread updated, thanks !

Comment: @MohammadAli you really did help me, feel yourself free to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally recommend that you use either a dedicated power supply or a usb to 12v dc-dc boost converter like [this](http://m.ebay.ca/itm/DC-DC-Converter-USB-Step-Up-Boost-Module-DC-5V-to-12V-Power-Supply-Solar-charger-/281128296063). Furthermore do check whether or not your fan is capable of detecting a 3.3v pwm signal as that is the max and only voltage the pi's gpio operates on. which means that you will likely also need a dc-dc boost converter on your pwm signal as well.

Answer (score 0):

"the thing is i can't find on the internet a similar project"
This is for the **simple reason** that it will **NOT** work.

You are likely to **blow up the Pi**.

On top of that you don't actually **need** a fan.

Comment: I'm getting mixed answers here, could you explain me why it would not work please ? Would it work through a relay with 12v battery powering the fan ?

Comment: @Corn Poorly asked questions with no supporting information tend to attract speculation. Realistically no one can answer. Connecting an (unspecified) 12V powered device (presumably intended for a desktop PC) to a 3.3V GPIO is unlikely to work, and risks damage. My "answer" was more intended to **warn** of the risk. This in addition to the fact that the (unspecified) Pi is unlikely to be able to supply sufficient current from your (unspecified) power supply.